# Operator overloading - compare object with integer

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

How do I overload the operator < if I have the Object itself on the leftside and an integer on the right side?

I know how to overload the operator "<" **if** I want to compare the object with itself . i.e

```
  bool NumberClass::operator<(NumberClass integer) {

if (this->integer < integer.number) {
    return true;
} else
    return false;
 }
```

where number is a private member of the class NumberClass

This works when I make an object of NumberClass but ***how do I design the operator-function 
if I want to compare the objects data member with an integer?***

Comment: The same way, just with a different parameter type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should do the trick:

```
bool NumberClass::operator<(int integer_) {
  return (this->integer < integer_);
}
```

BTW, it is considered bad style to make an if statement that only separates two return true/false statements. That should be written directly as done in my example.

Answer (score 2):

So you have `NumberClass` on both the left-hand side and right-hand side of `operator <`, correct?

```
bool NumberClass::operator<( const NumberClass &rhs ) const
{
    return integer < rhs.integer;  
}
```

If you want to compare against a plain `int` instead, then you just change the parameter type:

```
bool NumberClass::operator<( int rhs ) const
{
    return integer < rhs;  
}
```

Both can coexist, because C++ allows overloading.

Some style notes:

- You don't need `this` in the methods.
- `rhs` means "right hand side".  You will see this in a lot of `operator` definitions.
- You can return the boolean result of the compare directly.  This is usually preferred over wrapping it in an `if` statement as you had.
- You should declare these methods `const`, so that they can work with `const` qualified instances of the class.